# Pandas Series fillna with default date

Tags: python, pandas

How do I fill in NAN values in dataframe with a default date of 2015-01-01

what do I use here `df['SIGN_DATE'] = df['SIGN_DATE'].fillna(??, inplace=True)`

```
>>>df.SIGN_DATE.head()
0    2012-03-28 14:14:18
1    2011-05-18 00:41:48
2    2011-06-13 16:36:58
3    nan
4    2011-05-22 23:43:56

Name: SIGN_DATE, dtype: object
    type(df.SIGN_DATE)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df['SIGN_DATE'].fillna(value=pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015'), inplace=True)
```